# Visual Studio - Deleted files keep coming back

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET project where i added a folder in the project directory. Now that I don't need the folder, I deleted it from the project directory but whenever I reopen the solution, it keeps coming back. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you delete through Visual Studio Solution Explorer or through Windows File Explorer?

Comment: I had deleted it from the Windows File Explorer. Removing the references from the vbproj file did the trick. Thanks anyways !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a missing folder is referenced in your project (.csproj/.vbproj) file then on load it will be recreated.

Remove the unneeded folder using Solution Explorer and this will remove the references, or alternatively open the project file in a text editor and remove the referencing lines manually.